# CUDA 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 - conflicting drivers

Tags: cuda

I've followed the NVIDIA guide to installing CUDA on Ubuntu, using the .deb file and then calling `sudo aptitude install cuda`.

`dpkg --list | grep nvidia` now shows :

```
ii  nvidia-367                                 367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57
ii  nvidia-367-dev                             367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-modprobe                            367.48-0ubuntu1                                             amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-367                      367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
rc  nvidia-prime                               0.8.2                                                       amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            367.48-0ubuntu1                                             amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

As you can see, it looks like I have 367.57 and 367.48 running concurrently. As a result, I get errors like

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_367_uvm': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

I can't figure out how to fix this issue. Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: This is a Ubuntu package management issue, not a programming question. You world be better served asking it somewhere else.

Comment: The [nvidia guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#abstract) doesn't have `sudo aptitude install cuda` anywhere in it.  It does however explain how to remove old installations.  You might try doing that and try again.

Comment: @RobertCrovella : http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation

It isn't very clear on removing old installations. That being said, this isn't an old installation - this is a fresh Ubuntu install. I just followed the directions in this guide, using the package manager version, as the generic installer ( .run ) kept failing to disable Nouveau drivers, and when I tried manually, I got no display whatsoever and had to reinstall the OS again.

Comment: show me where `aptitude` appears in that document.  Section 2.7 of that document is pretty clear on how to remove old installations. And as already pointed out, this question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I used `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`, which is generally not an issue. As for being off-topic, I've asked it elsewhere, as was recommended. I was merely answering your comment.

Comment: Just install drivers and Cuda with .run option.
Download drivers from Nvidia page and run it in command line, and do the same for Cuda, choose, .run file installation. 
I can confirm this setup, at 2016.12.26 I am running Ubuntu 16.04, Cuda 8.0.44, NVIDIA x86_64-375.26 drivers With Dual GTX 980Ti GPUs, CuDNN 5105, CNMeM. Gcc version 5.4.0, Using it with Keras on both backends TensorFlow and Theano.

Answer (score 0):

I am running a setup identical with yours. I think you misnamed the module, it should be nvidia_uvm. I used the Ubuntu supplied Nvidia drivers (same versions as yours, and have an identical mix of 367.48 and 57 versions.